# How is the Following Picture Possible?

Tags: time-series, probability, poisson-distribution, markov-process, queueing

[image]

Source: https://blog.wolfram.com/2013/03/21/the-mathematics-of-queues/

In this picture, it would appear that multiple customers can enter and exit the queue at the same time. In real life, this is entirely possible - but how exactly can this be modelled by a Markov Chain or by a Stochastic Process? Is it possible to have a stochastic process that can accommodate "multiple events at the same time"?

Is this what the "jump process" is used for? Or is this accomplished using the "compound poisson process"? E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_process

Comment: I am not sure the picture shows two customers entering at exactly the same time: there is always a delay.

Comment: It is possible to have a process like your idea: for example a distribution of gaps between events, and each event having a distribution of a possible number of entries and exits (which may depend on the number already in the system).  It is just that such a process becomes more complicated to analyse than the simple M/M/1 queue that was simulated to produce that chart